# TFS Builds - How to customise script to identify when not to build assemblies?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have custom build definitions that builds all projects even if the only files that have been updated since the last build are css/javascript files.

You do not need to build assemblies when css/javascript files have been updated.
For the given scenario mentioned above, I want the build script to just copy those css/javascript files over to the web server.

How do I go about making my build script stop building assemblies when the only files that have been updated since the last build are css/javascript files? And then with those files, copy it over to the web server?

Comment: Be careful how you determine that it is "building" unnecessary files. Is it _compiling_ them, or is it just linking files which have already been compiled. Also, you would do better to worry about how long the build takes.

Answer (score 0):

First, enable diagnostic logging into a file and rebuild.  Examine that log and identify the target that is rebuilding and look for the output saying "rebuilding *project* due to *cause*".

How are you kicking off the build?  Do you have any targets that *touch* files during the build process?  Are these rebuilding because an aggressive target is minifying .js output, and the updated timestamp on the .js file is triggering a rebuild?

If that doesn't help, update your post to include the MsBuild script.